# Chart.JS: How to add Data to a specific dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Currently I use this to add data to my charts:

```
 targetChart.addData(value,targetDataSetIndex,"");
```

because I thought that this would add data to a specific set, adding an empty label.

But this doesnt work.

I then tried doing it myself by introducing a new method in the Chart.js script, like this:

```
    addDataValueToSpecificDataSet :function(value,datasetIndex)
    {
        this.datasets[datasetIndex].points.push(new this.PointClass({
            value: value,
            label: label,
            x: this.scale.calculateX(this.scale.valuesCount + 1),
            y: this.scale.endPoint,
            strokeColor: this.datasets[datasetIndex].pointStrokeColor,
            fillColor: this.datasets[datasetIndex].pointColor
        }));
    }
```

But when executing it isnt found. Where in Chart.JS do I need to put this so that it is accessible from the outside? Or can someone please tell me how im supposed to add data to a chart with multiple datasets one by one. I cant find it in the documentation which covers everything BUT adding and removing data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me (you probably just need to add update):

```
function addData() {
  myBarChart.data.labels[12] ="2017";
  myBarChart.data.labels[13] ="2018";
  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[12] = 500;
  myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[13] = 600;
  myBarChart.update();
}
```

CodePen: [Add/Remove adjust data Chart.js](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/gwdYzr?editors=0010)

Comment: Yeah in the meantime I noticed that Im using an outdated version of Chart.Js and thats why I cant find what I'm looking for in the documentation of the current version ^^ But thanks anyway.